# How to create a http client with tcp keep-alive using the method POST?

Tags: http, post, keep-alive

I need to create a http client with tcp keep-alive.

I have succeed in creating it with get method, but I want the first packet to use the Post method with the register info.

When I replace the GET with POST in the http header, the server send the fin/ack soon.

What's wrong with Post Header?

[The wireshark pic with the post header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH5Yq.png)

[The wireshark pic with the post header 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS2oF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I lost the Content-Length in the post header.

When I add the Content-Length, the server do not send the fin/ack.